# Обновление базы данных dataGridView с адаптером С#

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net, datagridview

Приветствую. Есть БД. Таблица из базы отображается в dataGridView. Пытаюсь отредактировать и сохранить таблицу из dataGridView в БД через адаптер.

```
        public static SqlDataAdapter Createadapter()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE customers SET customer_phone = @phone,
                                                customer_Email = @MAIL",conn);
        updateCommand.Parameters.Add(@"phone", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "customer_phone");
        updateCommand.Parameters.Add(@"MAIL", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50, "customer_Email");
        adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;

        return adapter;
    }
```

Возникает такая проблема - абсолютно все значение столбца принимают значение отредактированной ячейки этого столбца.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как исправить? Спасибо

Comment: правильно, вы ведь не указали, какие именно строки нужно обновлять. Добавьте условие WHERE в запрос.

Comment: спасибо @Mr Scapegrace. так и думал что забыл какую то мелочь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо  @Mr Scapegrace!
поменял строку команды на:

```
    SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE customers SET customer_phone = @phone,
                                                customer_Email = @MAIL WHERE (id = @ID)",conn);
```

Добавил :

```
      SqlParameter parametr = updateCommand.Parameters.Add(@"ID",SqlDbType.Int,10,"id");
        parametr.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
```

И все заработало!